# Implementing Angular Masonry for Videos instead of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have to use angular masonry grid styles for videos instead of images, I referred most of the angular masonry docs and all I could find is it of using for images.I replaced the img tag and used video tag but still it doesn't seems working.Can anyone help me out how to include videos.

Comment: It would be very very hard to implement such a thing as video controls are nearly impossible to make responsive. If you still want to try something take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: I don't agree with @Mandeep Jain. It is possible for sure, we can customise the script easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. At last I got it worked, I replaced the img tag with video tag and it is working perfectly. Try [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/pinterest-like-responsive-grid) and replace the tags.